# React Native Axios request on Android returns "Network Error"

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, reactn

## i am getting same error in my react native android so I fix this

[image]

[image]
by implementing this thing you can fix and resolve this error from react native android.
for ios you have to implment add this thing into plist.info

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.dummyapi.io</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
     </dict>
     </dict>`
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?